# How to set Google App Engine java Content-Type to UTF-8

Tags: java, google-app-engine, utf-8

It seems I cannot get UTF-8 encoding to be sent in the response headers.
I tried using this to no avail:

```
resp.setHeader("Content-Encoding", "utf-8");
```

Does anyone know when is this bug to be fixed or is **there a workaround**?

References:

- http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/68a480cb7bec869e
- http://www.ozelwebtasarim.com/index.php/google/10004-google-app-engine-java-utf-8-character-encoding-problem

Comment: just a reminder, it looks like the default system encoding for app engine is not utf-8, so anything that relies on a default system encoding will need to be modified to use the utf-8, eg an OutputStreamReader-

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per [the w3 reference](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.5), `Content-Encoding` is for such things as gzip, deflate, compress -- *not* for "how is Unicode encoded in the body". What you need is e.g.

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

i.e., the `charset` attribute of `Content-Type`.

Answer (score 0):

I added this line to the top of my jsp page (that contained the form) and the error is gone

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
```